# Page scrolls up on clicking react datepicker icon

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I use `react-datepicker`

```
if (isMultiline) {
      popperModifiers.offset.offset = MULTILINE_X_OFFSET;
      customInput = <MultilineDatePicker
        name={name}
        invalid={invalid}
        icon="date"
        type="text"
        label={label}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        onIconClick={this.openDatePicker}
        onCustomBlur={this.closeDatePicker}
      />;
```

```
  openDatePicker = () => {
    this.datePickerRef.current.setOpen(true);
  };

  closeDatePicker = () => {
    this.props.onChange(this.correctValue);
    this.datePickerRef.current.setOpen(false);
  };
```

Page automatically scrolls up on clicking datepicker icon. I cannot find solution :(

Comment: What is a `MultilineDatePicker`?

Comment: It's a custom realization with label and input field

Comment: We probably need to see it as well as any other relevant code, because I am not seeing anything that would cause a scroll here.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi is it okay to provide whole code from the current file? :)

Comment: It depends on big it is, if it's too big you lower your chance of people being interested in the question. But if it's relevant to the problem, then just add it.

Comment: What was the issue or did you ever get a fix?